# Is it possible to get equivalences of Western Electric Rules in non normal distribution with percentile values?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, quantiles, quality-control

I am not a statistician and I am a bit lost with these concepts, but I will try to explain my situation.

I have a non-normally distributed data, and I am trying to apply the Western Electric Rules to that dataset. The mean value of my dataset is 0.6 and the standard deviation is 0.3.

The values of the dataset are in the range [0,1]. In this sense, some Western Electric Rules will never be filled due to, for example: 3*std + mean > 1.

My question is: is there any way to simulate the Western Electric Rules with the percentiles instead of with the standard deviation? How can I do?

Comment: It sounds like you need a special control charting procedure for these data, but which one it should be depends on the nature of these data: what do these numbers represent and how are they measured?